# Head Recursion Java

Tags: java, recursion

Can someone explain why the last two lines are printed? I understand that the 2nd call to the function will set the count to 0 after printing: Hello, value of count: 1. So, once we pass this argument 0 to our method, the ***if*** statement will return true and exit the method upon hitting the ***return*** statement, but it appears that the program is going to the ***else*** statement even when ***if*** is *true*! I debugged and saw the step by step analysis, but still not understanding it. I think only the first two lines should be printed and the program should terminate after that. Also, why the counter is incremented in the last println statement? Thanks!

```
public class RecursionEx {
    void myMethod( int counter){
        if(counter == 0){ //Base Case
            return;    
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hello, "+"value of count: "+counter);
            myMethod(--counter);
            System.out.println("value of count: "+counter);
            return;
        }
    }
    public static void main (String args[]){
        new RecursionEx().myMethod(2);;
    }
}

/*
OUTPUT:
Hello, value of count: 2
Hello, value of count: 1
value of count: 0
value of count: 1
*/
```

Comment: Local variables of a method are stored in stack. Therefore each method invocation gets its own copy of these variables.

Comment: Your indentation is terrible, it makes your code painful to read. Please fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to understand if you think sequentially about what happens:

1. Method called with value "2" (depth=1)
2. Message "Hello, value of count: 2" printed
3. Method called recursively with value "1" (depth=2)
4. Message "Hello, value of count: 1" printed
5. Method called recursively with value "0" (depth=3)
6. Method at depth 3 returns without doing anything
7. Method at depth 2 prints "value of count: 0"
8. Method at depth 2 returns
9. Method at depth 1 prints "value of count: 1"
10. Method at depth 1 returns

Each recursive invocation of the myMethod() happens within the execution of the previous invocation and the invocation of that calling method doesn't continue until the recursively called version returns. So, when you call myMethod(--counter) your current invocation of myMethod() is effectively suspended and a new one begins. Once this new method finishes the previous one continues where it left off ***with the values for all its local variables untouched***.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what happening at each level of recursion:

```
myMethod(2) is called.
    counter is 2, not 0, so the else is performed.
    "Hello, value of count: 2" is printed.
    counter is decremented to 1, and myMethod(1) is called.
        counter is 1, not 0, so the else is performed.
        "Hello, value of count: 1" is printed.
        counter is decremented to 0, and myMethod(0) is called.
            counter is 0, so the `return` (base case) is executed.
        Here, counter is still 0, so "value of count: 0" is printed.
    Here, counter is still 1, so "value of count: 1" is printed.
```

No incrementing is happening.  The value of `counter` is different at each level of recursion, and the decrement of `counter` at one level has no effect on the value of `counter` at the previous level.

Answer (score 1):

```
myMethod(--counter);
System.out.println("value of count: "+counter);
```

The key to understanding recursion is that the when it hits the base case it returns and then the next line of code is executed. So here when it goes inside the if and returns since counter is 0, the next Print statement is executed. Now the counter is 0, so it prints 0. After that it again returns from the myMethod(1) call and agin the print statement is executed. Here the counter was 1, so it prints 1.

Answer (score 1):

Several things I would like to point out to help the OP:

- a "return" exits a method, but does not exit the entire recursion. Also, it does not terminate the program, only the method.
- when you call myMethod(--counter), you are not only passing in the decremented counter to myMethod(), but also actually modifying the counter value. Therefore, the 2nd println() will ALWAYS print the value of current counter-1.
- when you call myMethod(anyNumber), the execution of the method receives a COPY of the "anyNumber". Therefore, any modification to "anyNumber" will not affect the copy that is being used by the recursive call.

A similar, but simplified example

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        foo(2);
    }

    static void foo(int num)
    {
        if (num == 0)
            return;

        System.out.println("before: " + num);

        foo(num - 1);

        System.out.println("after: " + num);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
before: 2
before: 1
after: 1
after: 2
```

PS. Please format your code before posting.